How to set up a basic crystal oscillator circuit?
I would like to make a clock circuit. For that I need to use a 2-pin crystal oscillator ran at 10MHz with 5V. I read that I shouldn't just use the crystal by itself. Capacitors, resistors, inductors, etc. are needed. What is a basic setup?
[

From my basic website

The terms you are using have subtle differences.
A crystal is a two-terminal passive component with impedance that changes in frequency and has some resonance frequency labeled on it. It does not oscillate or do anything else by itself.
An oscillator is an active circuit with active comoonents that takes in power from a supply and uses feedback for oscillation, producing for example square or sine wave output.
A crystal oscillator is an oscillator circuit with crystal being used as the frequency setting feedback element.
You have many ways of making a crystal oscillator, and they do require some resistors and capacitors depending on which oscillator design you use. Inductors are only required for overtone crystals, when frequency goes past 30 MHz or so.
You want a crystal oscillator with 10 MHz output. You can just buy an oscillator module or design one yourself.
You can do a Pierce crystal oscillator with unbuffered CMOS inverter such as 4069 or 74HCU04.
There are many websites and application notes from crystal manufacturers how to design it.
If you want an easy solution, put the crystal to a MCU and write a program to output the clock.

I want to make a 10MHz signal. Sorry if I was unclear about that.
